# Pseudo code, complexity

Tags: function

so I need to write two pseudo-codes for the fibonacci function. I started with a recursive definition, namely

```
function VAL=fibonacci(N)  
    if N=1 then  
        VAL=1  
    else if N=2 then  
        VAL=1  
    else  
        VAL=fibonacci(N-1)+fibonacci(N-2)  
    end if  
    return VAL  
end function
```

Moreover I wrote the non-recursive version in the following manner:

```
function VAL=fibonacci(N)  
    f=1  
    VAL=1  
    for I=3 to N  
        f_new=VAL+f  
        f=VAL  
        VAL=f_new  
    end for  
    return VAL  
end function
```

It would be of great help if somebody could check if that makes any sense. So the question now is: We assume that the additional cost of adding two integers is one unit. Estimate the total computational cost of the first recursive function and the second non-recursive function in terms of N.

Since a few people have tried to explain it to me without success, I would every grateful if somebody could give me the solution so I can try to understand it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first function, you use the recursive to calculate the value of Fibonacci which has many repeat calculations, for example: f(5) = f(4) + f(3), f(4) = f(3) + f(2). Here, f(3) is been calculated twice which waste the time and memory space and f(2) will be calculated three times: f(5)->f(4)->f(3)->f(2), f(5)->f(4)->f(2), f(5)->f(3)->f(2). assum input parameter N is big enough, 
f(n) = f(n - 1) + f(n - 2)
...
there are very large repeat calculations in the function. From the theoretical analysis, the time complexity is O(1.618^n)

But in the second function, every n in the function will be calculated only once, so the time complexity is O(n).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I think I understood what you said for the second function. So the cost would be 1 if N=1 or 2 and 3/2 for larger N? But what could be the computational cost in terms of N for the first function?

Comment: The complexity of first function based on the recurrence equation: f(n) = f(n - 1) + f(n - 2) + O(1). 1.618=(1+sqrt(5))/2 which is the golden ratio in math theoretical analysis. We want to find a function satisfies this rule: f(n) = f(n - 1) + f(n - 2) = > x^n = x^(n - 1) + x^(n - 2) => x^2 = x + 1 => x = (1+sqrt(5))/2 = 1.618

Comment: Great, makes sense. So the cost would be O((1.618^n)/2) units?

Comment: In time complexity of O, constant complexity will be ignored, so the time complexity is O(1.618^n)

Comment: Great thanks a lot. I am still a bit confused with the other part, O(n). How could I come to that conclusion?

Comment: In the second funtion, the none-recursive version use a loop to calculation the f(n), every n >= 3 will use n - 2 loop iteration, so the time complexity is O(n - 2) = O(n)

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: My pleasure, please accept my answer if it is useful for you, thanks

Comment: Sorry, for asking again but why are you taking x^n and not something else?